# A Contact page with ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a contact page and this page shall either show a form or a success message or a failure message, so basically something like this:

```
@model MyApp.Models.ContactData

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>

...Some static content...


If page was opened the first time
    -> Render a form here
Else If form was posted and data successfully processed
    -> Render a success message here
Else If form was posted but error occurred during processing
    -> Render a failure message here

...Some static content...


</div>
```

I don't know what's the best way to achieve this with MVC 3. Do I create three completely separate views (which is something I'd like to avoid because of the static content which would be the same for all three views)? Or could I create three partial views and then decide based on an additional flag I could put into the model class which partial view to render? Or can I inject somehow the partial views dynamically from the controller into the view?

The controller I have so far looks like this:

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContactData contactData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ContactService service = new ContactService();
            bool result = service.Process(contactData);

            return ?; // What do I return now? It must somehow depend on result.
        }
        else
            return View(contactData));
    }

}
```

I had a similar page and behaviour with ASP.NET WebForms and the solution was there to put the three variable blocks of markup into `asp:Panel` controls and then switch on or off the `Visible` flag of those panels from code-behind. I guess I need quite another approach with ASP.NET MVC to reach the same goal.

What is the best way?

Thank you for suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this way:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Contact contactData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ContactService service = new ContactService();
            if (service.Process(contactData))
            {
                TempData["Success"] = "Your success message.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                TempData["Error"] = "Your fail message.";                   
            }
        }
        return View(contact);
    }
```

Comment: Your solution seems to have an advantage over p.campbell's solution (see my comment to his answer). How long does `TempData` live in contrast to the ViewBag? It seems to survive `RedirectToAction` which is not the case for the ViewBag apparently.

Comment: TempData exists for scenarios like these. Data is available only for one more request. However, if you need the data for a few more subsequent requests (say for some wizard), you can 'prolong' this by calling Keep() methods. See more details on MSDN: http://goo.gl/rEQ03

Comment: This looks indeed like the perfect way. In the meantime I have learned that this pattern even has a name: "Post/Redirect/Get (PRG) pattern" and TempData is made to support this pattern. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use the ViewBag to help achieve all this. Of course it's a dynamic, so you can add & check for any prop you want/need/expect.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(ContactData contactData)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        ContactService service = new ContactService();
        bool result = service.Process(contactData);
        ViewBag.ContactSuccess = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewBag.ModelStateErr= "some err";
    }

    return View(contactData));
}
```

Then in your View:

```
if (ViewBag.ContactSuccess !=null && ((bool)ViewBag.ContactSuccess))
{
        //thanks for posting!
}
else
{  
    if (ViewBag.ModelStateErr !=null)
    {
        //show that we have an err
    }
    else
    {
        //we have no err nor a 'true' contact success yet
        //write out the form
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like this solution. It works, but it will render a from with input data after submit.

Comment: this results in a big ugly if block in your view markup. Not ideal for optimization and maintenance.

Comment: @frennky: Why would this render a form after submit? You never reach the second else-block in the markup after a post, do you?

Comment: The logic I want is more like: `if (result) ViewBag.ContactSuccess = true; else ViewBag.ContactFailure = true;` And if the ModelState is invalid I want to rerender the form with usual validation notifications. But that's a minor point, it's clear how I can achieve this logic. Important for me was to see that a solution using the ViewBag is possible and how. Thanks for this easy solution!

Comment: @Slauma you are correct, I wasn't paying enough attention to the view. Personally, I try to have minimal logic inside views. The solution I provided would have one if block to check for Messages. And since you'll probably have more forms in your web app, you can wrap that message logic into a partial or a helper, removing it from contact view and making it available for reuse elsewhere.

Comment: I just discovered that the solution has a little drawback: If the form is submitted successfully and therefore I reach the page with `ViewBag.ContactSuccess = true` and the user then clicks the Refresh button in the browser, a new post is triggered (after usual warning message in the browser) and the form data are submitted again although the form is invisible. Using `RedirectToAction` didn't help because the ViewBag data seem to get lost then. freenky's answer (with `TempData` instead of `ViewBag`) doesn't have this problem. Hm,I must still learn a lot of stuff to understand these subtleties.

Comment: Folks, suggest using/rendering partial views if you don't want all that markup. I painted my answer in broad strokes. It's all in how your view is designed.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like that you can issue an ajax call on the client side, and based on the Json result, you can render different content from the client side.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest coding up three different Views

- index.cshtml
- contactSuccess.cshtml
- contactFail.cshtml

Then in your Controller, you'll have similar code as before

```
public class ContactController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(ContactData contactData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ContactService service = new ContactService();
            bool result = service.Process(contactData);

            return View("contactSuccess.cshtml"); 
        }
        else
            return View("contactFail.cshtml", contactData);
    }

}
```

This way each view has an independent and you don't have a big inline IF block in the middle of your markup.

**Alternatively** (and this is how I'd do it) you can have the index.cshtml contain three partials...

- _ContactForm.cshtml
- _ContactSuccess.cshtml
- _ContactFail.cshtml

and then you can load the partial views into the index view, and even swap them out dynamically using AJAX.

Comment: "...you can load the partial views into the index view...": This sounds like a good solution, but I don't know how to do it. If I understand you correctly your code snippet provides three completely different views which is not ideal because all three views have common parts of markup which I would need to copy then. Is it possible to inject different partial views dynamically WITHOUT using Ajax?